# Быстрое сохранение файла на Python tkinter

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Дали задание по учебе, сделать текстовый редактор по определенным критериям. Более или менее реализовал все функции, осталась одна, с быстрым сохранением файла. Прошу вашей помощи.

```
import fileinput
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *


def close_win():
    root.destroy()


def about():
    messagebox.showinfo("About", "Выполнил студент группы ПБТ-42\nПетровский Алексей Михайлович")


def do_popup(event):
    popup = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
    popup.add_command(label="Save", command=save_file)
    popup.add_command(label="About", command=about)
    popup.add_command(label="Exit", command=_exit)
    try:
        popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
    finally:
        popup.grab_release()


def open_file():
    txtView.delete(1.0, END)
    open = askopenfilename()
    file_name.configure(text=open)
    for i in fileinput.input(open):
        txtView.insert(END, i)


def save_as_file():
    save_as = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt")
    letter = txtView.get(1.0, END)
    f = open(save_as, "w")
    f.write(letter)
    f.close()
    file_name.configure(text=f.name)


def save_file():
    None


def _exit():
    if askyesno("Выход", "Хотите сохранить файл перед выходом?"):
        save_as_file()
    root.destroy()


def new_file():
    if askyesno("Новый файл", "Хотите сохранить файл перед созданием нового?"):
        save_as_file()


root = Tk()
m = Menu(root)  # создается объект Меню на главном окне
root.config(menu=m)  # окно конфигурируется с указанием меню для него

fm = Menu(m, tearoff=0)  # создается пункт меню с размещением на основном меню (m)
m.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fm)   # пункту располагается на основном меню (m)
fm.add_command(label="New", command=new_file)
fm.add_command(label="Open...", command=open_file)
fm.add_command(label="Close...", command=close_win)
fm.add_command(label="Save...", command=save_file)
fm.add_command(label="Save as...", command=save_as_file)
fm.add_separator()
fm.add_command(label="Exit", command=_exit)

hm = Menu(m, tearoff=0)  # второй пункт меню
m.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=hm)
hm.add_command(label="About", command=about)

file_name = Label(root, text="Здесь будет имя открытого файла")
file_name.pack()

scr = Scrollbar(root)
scr.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
txtView = Text(root, yscrollcommand=scr.set, width=100, height=20)
txtView.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scr.config(command=txtView.yview)


root.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А в чем смысл try без except?

Comment: да спасибо, забыл уже про этот участок, с одного сайта стянул по созданию popup меню. и забыл убрать

Answer (score 1):

asksaveasfile и askopenfile могут сами писать и читать оркрытый ими файл, поэтому нет необходимости в open

чтобы не закрывать файл f.close(), лучше использовать менеджер контекста with open(file, "w") as f:

```
def open_file():
    txtView.delete(1.0, END)
    file = askopenfile()
    for i in file:
        txtView.insert(END, i)
    file_name['text'] = file.name

def save_as_file():
    file = asksaveasfile(defaultextension=".txt")
    file.write(txtView.get(1.0, END))
    file_name['text'] = file.name

def save_file():
    file = file_name['text']
    if file not in ["Здесь будет имя открытого файла", None, '']:
        with open(file, "w") as f:
            f.write(txtView.get(1.0, END))
```

Comment: спасибо большое. Про with знал, но совсем забыл про него.

Answer (score 0):

Сам сообразил)) ну может кому понадобится, либо у кого есть советы по коду, с удовольствием учту.

```
def save_file():
    file = file_name.cget("text")
    if file != "Здесь будет имя открытого файла" or None:
        letter = txtView.get(1.0, END)
        f = open(file, "w")
        f.write(letter)
        f.close()
        file_name.configure(text=f.name)
```

Comment: Наверное, Вы хотели написать `if file != "Здесь будет имя открытого файла" or file != None:`

Comment: проверку на None можно убрать, просто когда открываешь файл и не выбираешь, а жмешь отмена, лейбл становится пустым. Но даже если вписать потом в текстовое поле что-то, и нажать save, то файл не создастся. Так что большое спасибо за наводку)

Comment: заметил в консоли ошибку, FileNotFoundError при отмене открытия файла или сохранении пустого. Так что прописал try...except для функций open_file, new_file и save_file